# WordPress embed link doesn't react when clicked

Tags: wordpress

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Ivij.png)

Here is the website with the problem as the title.
http://gophilippines.media/itcamp02/

When I try to click the WordPress embed link card, it doesn't do anything.

Does anyone know what's wrong and perhaps some idea to fix?

I also disabled all the plugins yet the link doesn't react...

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please edit your question to get a suitable answer faster. You should show us some code, not just links. This can help: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

The  element of the link contains an attribute `target="_top"`. This attribute will try to   open the linked document in the full body of the window (See [this](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_target.asp) for more info).
You can remove the attribute or change it to another that does the work for you.

Comment: Thank you so much Eric for the comment...but changing the target attribute didn't work.